# How to align the image inside the td with proper spacing

Tags: html, css, mjml

I want to align the image properly inside the `td` for the following.

[image]

I want to have like this,

[image]

I've written MJML code and generated the CSS.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 0;word-break:break-word;">
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <![endif]-->
        <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="float:none;display:inline-table;">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:4px;vertical-align:middle;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:20px;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:0;height:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:20px;">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                      <img height="20" src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('assets/theme/generics/social/external_mail/facebook.png')) }}" style="border-radius:3px;display:block;" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <![endif]-->
        <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="float:none;display:inline-table;">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:4px;vertical-align:middle;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:20px;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:0;height:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:20px;">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                      <img height="20" src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('assets/theme/generics/social/external_mail/twitter.png')) }}" style="border-radius:3px;display:block;" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <![endif]-->
        <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="float:none;display:inline-table;">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:4px;vertical-align:middle;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:20px;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-size:0;height:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:20px;">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.linkedin.com/company/&title=&summary=&source=" target="_blank">
                      <img height="20" src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('assets/theme/generics/social/external_mail/linkedin.png')) }}" style="border-radius:3px;display:block;" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - we need to see the code, how those icons are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this code. This will work in your case.

```
<mj-style>
  /* Adjust the styles as needed */
  td {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Center the image horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* Center the image vertically */
  }
  td img {
    max-width: 100%; /* Optional: Ensure the image doesn't exceed the cell width */
  }
</mj-style>
```

Comment: I dont think this will work in every case. The question is about mjml - i.e. getting things acceptable to email clients - and quite a lot still don't implement flex.

Comment: I think that using flex is the best optimal solution because if we try to do it with align, padding etc. That will vary screen to screen but the flex box behavior will remain same for all screens and will work in every case.

Comment: flex would be good were this a standard website but it’s not. Not all email clients have implemented flex at this time.

Comment: It's essential to use the tools and techniques that are compatible with the majority of email clients not for some. Rules are not made on exceptions. We have to choose the solution which works for most.

Comment: It depends on your audience requirement as to whether selecting for 'most' is OK or not. I believe flex is supported by quite a few email clients but some that might be important for my audience base may not be - so, we can't make a rule for everybody about this.

Comment: I have done this my approach, everyone got theirs.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `position:relative` for your container and `position:absolute` for your images which you want to change their place and change their position with `bottom`,`top`,`right`,`left` css properties but use `%` as unit while you are dealing with these four attributes because using other units causes problem for responsiveness.
e.g:

```
.container{
position:relative
}

.image-1{
position:absolute;
right:3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the mj-social tag in MJML? If yes, then there shouldn't be an alignment problem.

Check the following example:
https://mjml.io/try-it-live/6zI7es-2ZK

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>

    <mj-section padding="50px" background-color="#F5F2EE">
      <mj-column>

        <mj-social padding="0px" mode="horizontal">
          <mj-social-element icon-size="24px" padding="0px 10px" src="https://mcusercontent.com/58cc6fdf204aea6e7442682a9/images/55d3502b-3868-12a8-ab9d-87a3d12a9032.png" href="https://www.facebook.com"> </mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element icon-size="24px" padding="0px 10px" src="https://mcusercontent.com/58cc6fdf204aea6e7442682a9/images/3addb932-a68a-4b89-3f41-7ef7266cb63b.png" href="https://www.instagram.com"> </mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element icon-size="24px" padding="0px 10px" src="https://mcusercontent.com/58cc6fdf204aea6e7442682a9/images/5fa019f8-ae25-e992-c483-9ad0ebbb94a9.png" href="https://twitter.com"> </mj-social-element>
        </mj-social>

      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>


  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```